# useState in react : how to get each props?

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to convert a class component to a functionnal component and i need to use useState.

However, in the example on the react doc page : https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html, i see `const [count, setCount] = useState(0);`

What is the point of the 0 ? What to do if the props has several constants i want to retrieve, how am i supposed to know or do which one is which one?

thank you

Comment: In that case 0 es the initial value. If you have more than one constant you might have: `const [count, setCount] = useState(0); const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false); const [name, setName] = useState("Juan");`

Comment: ok so the value passed to useState is the initial value of the const? so if i want to set the state to the props value i have to initialize it with useState and then set the value with props.constant_name right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood part 2 of your question but I will try to answer

1. the 0 in `useState(0)` => is an initial value you can put or Ignore it not a problem
2. the second part is based on my understanding to it => that you want to set more than 1 prop so you can use multiple `useState` because in functional components it's allowed or you can use the `useReducer` to manage it.

But if you want to know how to access each prop in the component it's easy. the component is a function that gives you an argument called props that contains all your props like that

```js
const component = (props) => {

  props // is an object that contains all your props
  
}
```

so you can access any props using `props.propname`

Answer (score 0):

Lets imagine you have a class component with props like this:

```js
interface IProps {
  foo: string
  bar: number
  baz: Array<string>
}

props: IProps = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: 5
  baz: ["baz"]
}
```

There are two way of converting this into hooks, you can either use the whole object or break it down, with the latter being the preferred option.

Using the whole object (assuming you are to initialize it with the default values from snippet above):

```js
const [props, setProps] = useState<IProps>(props)
```

and then it can be updated in jsx same as in class components:

```js
setProps(props => { ...props, props.foo: "newfoo" })
```

While this is going to work, it is better to break it down:

```js
const [foo, setFoo] = useState<string>()
const [bar, setBar] = useState<number>()
const [baz, setBaz] = useState<Array<string>>()
```

and then the state can be updated separately:

```js
setFoo("newfoo")
setBar(8)
setBaz(["newbaz"])
```

Notes:

In TypeScript the props has to be initialized with the values to conform with the interface. However, if you prefer not to include default values, you can define you interface like this:

```js
interface IProps {
  foo?: string
  bar?: number
  baz?: Array<string>
}
```

and then, you can initialize the props with `useState` as below:

```js
const [props, setProps] = useState<IProps>()
```

If you don't provide any value to the `useState`, it will initialize it automatically to the zero value of the corresponding type:

```js
useState<string>()
```

is equivalent to

```js
useState<string>("")
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot! but usually, from my experience, i dont have a defined interface or a defined name for the whole props, i just pass them along when creating the component. how do i do then? what if there is two numbers or two strings in the props?

Comment: That is all fine, you can just skip the typings and it will work just well! Pass over any props and initialize same as you would in plain JS.